# How to choose 1 random number from 2 different number ranges?

Tags: php, random

I need to get a random number that is between

```
0 - 80
```

and

```
120 - 200
```

I can do

```
$n1 = rand(0, 80);
$n2 = rand(120, 200);
```

But then I need to choose between `n1` and `n2`. Cannot do

```
 $n3 = rand($n1, $n2)
```

as this may give me a number between `80 - 120` which I need to avoid.

How to solve this?

Comment: In the beginning of your question, you specify the range of `1-80`, but the code reflects a range of `0-80`. Which did you mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since both ranges have different sizes (even if only by 1 number), to ensure good random spread, you need to do this:

```
$random = rand( 0, 200 - 39 );
if ($random>=120-39) $random+=39;
```

Fastest method. :)

The way this works is by pretending it's a single range, and if it ends up picking a number above the first range, we increase it to fit within the second range. This ensures perfect spread.

Comment: He fixed the question, both have the same range of 81 (0-80 and 120-200)

Comment: Agreed 2 calls to random is slower than one, but your implementation makes it much harder for a second programmer to follow the code and the benefit is probably only like 50-100ms? Which doesn't outweigh the cost for me :P

Comment: Np. There are other ways to do it, of course, but this one guarantee's good spread no matter the 2 ranges. :)

Answer (score 5):

Since both ranges have the same size you can simply use `rand(0, 1)` to determine which range to use.

```
$n = rand(0, 1) ? rand(0, 80) : rand(120, 200);
```

Comment: @ThiefMaster and what you mean by `since both ranges have the same size` is that the odds of a number in any of those two ranges being chosen is the same because its 50% / range-size right?

Comment: Not correct. It will not be uniformly random as a number on a shorter interval will more likely to be accepted. While it may be correct here because span is 80 in both, this is not true in general.

Comment: Again, the span is not 80 in both ranges. 200-120 = 80, 80 - 1 = 79, one is smaller than the other.

Comment: According to the most recent edit, the ranges are the same size.

Comment: @DanRedux its 81, 81, the OP clarified his question to say 0-80 and 120-200

Comment: Nevertheless, we should aim for the general case in our answers.

Comment: Np. Looks like he changed it to 0-80, so now either code will work. Just which one is faster. Mine only has 1 call to rand and an if statement, this one has 2 calls to rand and a ternary operator.

Comment: This answer isn't future proof because it would have to be re-implemented if at some point the ranges are (or could be, as in user specified) different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a new function for this as well called range.  Very easy to use, and can be located in the PHP Manual.

It allows you to input a minimum/maximum number to grab a range from.

```
<?php
echo range(0, 1000);
?
```

Technically though, you could also enter your own two numbers to serve as the number range.

Answer (score 1):

get two random numbers **$n1** and **$n2**

```
$n1 = rand(0, 80);
$n2 = rand(120, 200);
```

define new array called **$n3**

```
$n3=array();
```

add **$n1** and **$n2** into array **$n3** use array_push() function

```
array_push($n3,$n1,$n2);
```

use array_rand() function to find random index **$find_index** from array **$n3**.

```
$find_index=array_rand($n3,1);
```

show the result

```
echo $n3[$find_index];
```